# how to add user for docker mongodb

Tags: mongodb, docker

I follow the document of docker mongodb image to add a user for mongodb,:

```
$ docker run --name some-mongo -d mongo --auth
$ docker exec -it some-mongo mongo admin
```

the I tried to add a user but it comes error:

> 'it's not not authorized.'

I'm so confused , how to add a user? if I run without auth I can add a user but I don't know how to add --auth for it then.

Comment: @Rao I need help

Comment: Looks you are following official mongo here - https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/  Have you followed the given documentation links as well?

Comment: yeah, I know how to solve it now, it seems that the document is not clear enough.

Comment: @laoqiren if you have solved your issue, please post your solution as the answer. It will help others.